# React: How to wait until ref is available when inserted (rendered) within a second container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

**EDIT: better explanation**

**The context:**

I receive some plain HTML code from a 3rd server, which I want to

- insert in my React app
- modify it

**The vanilla JS approach**

- I can modify the string with regex and add any HTML tag with an `id`
- Then I can modify these elements through `getElementById`, as usual

**The React approach**

- I shouldn't use the DOM
- Then I should insert within the string some components that have a React ref inside
- The opposite (to insert some React components as plain HTML) would be through `ReactDOMServer.renderToString`
- So, when I inject the components with `ReactDOM.render()`, the problem is that the `render` method takes its time, so that if in the next line I try to use the ref that exists in the inserted component, is not yet there

**The question**

- How to do it? Usually I would put the code within a `useEffect` with a `[]` dependencies, but here I am `rendering` the component when the app is already mounted
- A quick workaround is to just do an async wait of 500 ms, and then I can access the `ref`, but for sure there has to be something better

---

This code fails, because when the `ref` is rendered it is still not available, so `ref.current` is undefined

How can I wait for it?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-ives-f7n7z?file=/src/App.js:0-556)

EDIT: I provide the code that works but through direct DOM, which I assume should be avoided

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function App() {
  const myref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const Com = () => <div ref={myref}>hello</div>;
    ReactDOM.render(<Com />, document.getElementById("container"));
    console.log(myref.current); // undefined
    document.getElementById('container').textContent = "direct DOM works"

   // the next line fails since the ref is not yet available
   // myref.current.textContent = "but this REF is not available"; // fails
  }, []);

  const plainhtml = '<div><div id="container"></div><div>some more content</div><div id="another">even more content</div></div>'; // this is some large HTML fetched from an external server

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: plainhtml }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `ReactDOM.render` inside a `useEffect`? You should just render it as a child, that way you would be able to use state to set the text content

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem you trying to solve? You want to update the `textContent`?

Comment: @aabbccsmith that useEffect is called when `plainhtml` is available (fetched from an external server), but the code example doesn't need to include this

Comment: @DennisVash I receive a html string from an external server which I can show with dangerouslySetInnerHTML, but then I want to insert there some React components, the way of doing this is through `.render()`, but then when I want to use the refs they're not available (they are if I wait few milliseconds). So the question is how to have access to them (which is what the code example shows)

Comment: @GWorking I've updated the answer, check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need to use a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) but encapsulating it within `useCallback` to make sure it only rerenders with the dependencies indicated (i.e. none `[]`), so that it is only executed when the component changes (as explained [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node))

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-fast-czqjp?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function App() {
  const measuredRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      node.textContent = "useCallback DOM also works";
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const Com = () => <div ref={measuredRef}>hello</div>;
    ReactDOM.render(<Com />, document.getElementById("container"));
    document.getElementById("container").textContent = "direct DOM works";
  }, []);

  const plainhtml = '<div id="container"></div>';

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: plainhtml }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`useEffect` with empty dependency array executes **after** the first render, therefore you will get the DOM ref in the callback:

```
const htmlString = '<div id="container">Hello</div>';

export default function App() {
  const myRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (myRef.current) {
      myRef.current.textContent = 'whats up';
    }
    console.log(myRef.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={myRef} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }} />
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }} />
    </div>
  );
}

/* App renders:
whats up
Hello
*/
```

[image: Edit nervous-glade-8rtxb]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question is specific about getting the ref available when inserted within a plain html code that is itself inserted with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: You need the component to mount in order to have the ref, I'll add an example of what 
I think you trying to achieve.

Comment: This is happening once I receive the plain html content, that I want to inject, but that I want to contain some components to change them. I can do it with vanilla document.getElementById, but trying to do it the React way (i.e. useRef)

Comment: Thanks again (for your time :)) but the quid is to insert this ref inside the `htmlString`

Comment: So just use append child and so on. You **got** the reference which is actually what you asked.

Comment: I'm afraid I am not explaining myself too well, the reference that you provide is not inside the `htmlString`, is a regular reference with no relation to `htmlString`. I ask for the former, I am not asking about how to get a reference in React (is that what is understood in the question?)

Comment: Do you just want the reference of the HTML that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` renders? Like `<div id="container" ref={myRef}>Hello</div>` in my example, you want this `myRef`?

Comment: (updated the question to better show what I want) What I'd want is to modify some elements that are inside the HTML that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` renders, not the whole HTML but some elements there